# Stick the pencil on the right

Tags: html, css, django

I'd like to center 'Status' with the pencil on the picture :

[image]

Here is the html code :

```
{{ headers }}

{% load i18n admin_static material_admin %}

{% if results %}
<div class="results">
  <table id="result_list" class="table bordered highlight">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        {% for header in result_headers %}
        {% if 'action_checkbox' in cl.list_display and forloop.counter == 1 %}
        <th class="action-checkbox">
            {{ header.text }}<label for="action-toggle">&nbsp;</label>
        </th>
        {% else %}
        <th scope="col" {{ header.class_attrib }}>
            {% if header.sortable %}
                {% if header.sort_priority == 0 %}
                    <a href="{{ header.url_primary }}" data-turbolinks="false">{{ header.text|capfirst }}</a>
                {% elif header.ascending %}
                    <a href="{{ header.url_primary }}" title="{% trans "Toggle sorting" %}" data-turbolinks="false"><i class="material-icons">arrow_upward</i>{{ header.text|capfirst }}</a>
                {% else %}
                    <a href="{{ header.url_remove }}" title="{% trans "Remove from sorting" %}" data-turbolinks="false"><i class="material-icons">arrow_downward</i>{{ header.text|capfirst }}</a>
                {% endif %}
            {% else %}
                <span>{{ header.text|capfirst }}</span>
            {% endif %}
        </th>{% endif %}{% endfor %}
        <th style="text-align:right;" style='postion: relative; right: 500px'>{% trans "Status" %}</th>
        {% if row_actions_template %}
        <th style="text-align:right;">{% trans "Actions" %}</th> 
        {% endif %}
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {% for row in results %}
      <tr class="{% cycle 'row1' 'row2' %}">
        {% for item in row.cols %}
          {{ item }}
        {% endfor %}
        <td class="material-icons">create</td>
        {% if row_actions_template %}
        <td class="row-actions">{% include row_actions_template with object=row.object %}</td>
        {% endif %}
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
{% endif %}

{% include "loanwolf/pagination.inc.html" %}
```

The two important lines here are `<th style="text-align:right;">{% trans "Actions" %}</th>` and `<td class="material-icons">create</td>`. How could I modify the pencil so that it could be a little bit on the right?

I thought I could do `<td class="material-icons" style='position: relative; 
 right: 200px'>create</td>`, but it didn't work.

Thanks in advance!

**P.S.** Please tell me if the question is unclear.

Comment: Can you post a snippet here by copying your html from DOM inspector.

Comment: @Nimish Sorry, but I do html since almost a week now. Could you tell me what you mean by your question?

Comment: Inspect the window. Copy the entire html and paste here in snippet. Add necessary css code also. Don't forget to add external libraries if used.

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the part about writing titles. That's not a great title. Also, that's not plain vanilla HTML. You are obviously using some kind of templating framework. Include the tag for that, or show the rendered HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Don't put your icons in a sub-table. Tables are not meant for layout, they're for displaying tabular data **only**.

Instead, apply the following to the table cell containing your action buttons:

```
.actions {
    text-align: right;
}
```

Then just make your icons a list of anchor tags. I'm having to make assumptions about how your icons are structured and their classes because you didn't include the icon html:

```
<td class="actions">
    <a href="#" class="icon icon-pencil">Action1</a>
    <a href="#" class="icon icon-clipboard">Action2</a>
    <a href="#" class="icon icon-plus">Action3</a>
</td>
```

Anchor tags are "inline" elements and will respond to `text-align` styles. Tables, divs, etc. are "block" elements and can't be aligned with text styles.